# Package Word Office 2010 with Macro to Run From Desktop

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working with office 2010 specifically microsoft word.Got some macros from this [link](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/NumberDocs.htm) and was able to generate serial numbers with the word document template.

My question is, how do I package this template for use by a third party.

The template will run from the desktop of the client machine.

Is there a link explaining how to package a Macro enabled template.

Below is he code:

```html
Sub AutoNew()
'
' AutoNew Macro
'
'

Order = System.PrivateProfileString("C:\dtp\Settings.Txt", _
        "MacroSettings", "Order")

If Order = "" Then
    Order = 1
Else
    Order = Order + 1
End If

System.PrivateProfileString("C:\dtp\Settings.txt", "MacroSettings", _
        "Order") = Order

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Order").Range.InsertBefore Format(Order, "00#")
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="DTP" & Format(Order, "00#")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to the Automate the Activation of a specific `Macro` (Say a `Userform`) when the user opens the Template then in your Project, navigate to

`Microsoft Word Objects` \ `ThisDocument` 
add the following `Sub`:

```
Private Sub Document_New()

Call SomeSub

End
```

Comment: I have used the sub AutoNew()  this runs the code when a new document is created. But I want to package the template and the macro and run it in another computer.

Comment: Are you macros and userforms  placed in your "Normal" project or in a somedox.docm projeft?

Comment: The macros and UserForms are stored in "Normal" project

Comment: See my second answer. For more details as to the process, I think your can figure it out. Otherwise comment and I can assist further.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is copy all your Macros and Userforms over to the "Document1" Project. To copy over simply click and drag the module or UserForm from the normal project to the Document1 project . You will need to copy any additional items you have saved in the Normal template too, such as headers or quick text or font styles.

Once this is all saved in the Document1 template,  you can then save it as a Macro Enabled  Template which can be backed up or shared with other parties